# How to query self referencing queries in Django for multiple objects

Tags: django, django-orm

Sorry for the bad title. I hope I can elaborate it better here. I have a  model class as below

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('Employee', null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

I want to make a query to find all the employees managed by a list of managers.

Something like this

```
SELECT
r.name
FROM employee l
JOIN employee r
ON l.id = r.manager_id
WHERE l.name in ('manger_1', 'manager_2');
```

How can I achieve this with Django ORM?

Comment: Instead of `models.ForeignKey('Employee', ...)` self referencing Foreign keys should use `self` to refer to the same model, i.e. `models.ForeignKey('self', ...)` (Although what you do would work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with an [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
Employee.objects.filter(manager__name__in=['manager_1', 'manager_2'])
```